# Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded in API and question marks in HTML

Tags: php, mysql

Im getting "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded" in my API response when I `echo json_last_error_msg();`

I tried many solutions. The webpage already has `<meta charset='UTF-8'>` and I also altered my database to support UTF-8 charset by using

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Third solution I tried is by adding options to my json encode.

```
json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

But still there is not change. Im not getting any response in my APIs if the response will have a single quote in it. And also my webpage is showing ? in places of other special characters.

Comment: I moved my entire (including the database) project to a new server. Everything was working fine on my previous server. When i moved to new server, i am facing this trouble.

Comment: Any chance that comma at the end of your first line of posted code is in your actual code? Can you post more code, such as what's before the `echo` so we can help determine what's actually the issue here?

Comment: @computercarguy , was a typo. Corrected it. The response that I json encoded might have a single qoute or any other special characters or characters in other languages. All these are fetched from the database.

Comment: ALTER DATASBASE will not fix data that's already broken in the database, but it's hard to tell if it is. How are you connecting to the database? Are you switching the connection to UTF-8? This is not done by default.

Comment: @Evert I tried switching to UTF-8. But that too did not fix the issue. The data shown well when i look at the database via phpmyadmin. But when I take the data through API or show them on website its showing this error.

Comment: @Evert The data is showing as ? on the webpage.

Comment: How did you 'switch to UTF-8' ?

Comment: @Evert $connection->set_charset("utf8");

Comment: What character do you *expect* to be printed (what's printed in phpmyadmin?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198070/discussion-between-sallu-salman-and-evert).

Comment: @Evert single quotes are shown as ? mark in api response. when i logged them in my server. im not getting any response when the response will have a single quote in it.
Also there are texts in other languages stored in database. those are shown as ? in my webpage